# jQuery: fadeIn fixed nav when scrolling past a certain point

Tags: jquery, fadein, css-position, sticky

I am trying to get my fixed navigation to fade in once my content area is 50px from the top of the window. I have gotten it to work, however I get an odd 'bounce' in the animation. The menu appears completely then goes invisible again and fades in. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function() {
    var vPos = $(window).scrollTop(); //The current scroll bar position
    var totalH = $('.content').offset().top; // Distance content from top
    var finalSize = totalH - vPos; // Get the difference of the distances

    console.log(finalSize);

    if( finalSize <= 50 ) {
        $('.sticky').fadeIn(300);       
    } else {
        $('.sticky').fadeOut(300);  
    }
});
```

It can be seen here: http://portfolio.stvartak.net/redesign

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a flag to avoid executing the fading stuff several times:

```
var flag=true;

$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var vPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
        totalH = $('.content').offset().top,
        finalSize = totalH - vPos;

    if( finalSize <= 50)
        if (flag) $('.sticky').fadeIn(300);
        flag=false;
    } else {
        if (!flag) $('.sticky').fadeOut(300);  
        flag=true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function() {
    var vPos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
    var totalH = $('.content').offset().top;     
    if( totalH <= vPos ) {
        $('.sticky').stop().fadeIn(300);       
    } else {
        $('.sticky').stop().fadeOut(300);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Still stutters for me and the animation is not smooth. Essentially the if statement should only run once. The problem is that it runs again the second you touch the scroll wheel and this interupts the animation. Is there is way so it only runs once? 

Please note that I can not use .unbind('scroll') as my parallax backgrounds need to remain bound to scroll. Thanks!